# amCharts center map

Tags: amcharts

I am using a world map of amCharts and when I lower the height the map zooms automatically to Nord America. Is there a way to set the centre of the map to be Europe and not Nord America? And I would like to remove the country names on mouse hover.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>map created with amCharts | amCharts</title>
  <meta name="description" content="map created using amCharts pixel map generator" />

  <!--
   This map was created using Pixel Map Generator by amCharts and is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.
   You may use this map the way you see fit as long as proper attribution to the name of amCharts is given in the form of link to https://pixelmap.amcharts.com/
   To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

   If you would like to use this map without any attribution, you can acquire a commercial license for the JavaScript Maps - a tool that was used to produce this map.
   To do so, visit amCharts Online Store: https://www.amcharts.com/online-store/
  -->

  <!-- amCharts javascript sources -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>

  <!-- amCharts javascript code -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var targetSVG = "M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z";
   AmCharts.makeChart("map",{
     "type": "map",
     "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
     "addClassNames": true,
     "fontSize": 15,
     "color": "#FFFFFF",
     "projection": "mercator",
     "backgroundAlpha": 1,
     "backgroundColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
     "dataProvider": {
      "map": "worldLow",
      "getAreasFromMap": true,
      "images": [
       {
        "top": 40,
        "left": 60,
        "width": 80,
        "height": 40,
        "pixelMapperLogo": true,
        "imageURL": "http://pixelmap.amcharts.com/static/img/logo.svg",
        "url": "http://www.amcharts.com"
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Brussels",
        "longitude": 4.2100,
        "latitude": 50.5100,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1,
        "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/brussels/"
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Berlin",
        "longitude": 13.2300,
        "latitude": 52.3100,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1,
        "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/berlin/"
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Graz",
        "longitude": 15.2600,
        "latitude": 47.4000,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1,
        "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/graz/"
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Sofia (coming soon)",
        "longitude": 23.33,
        "latitude": 42.7000,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Shanghai (coming soon)",
        "longitude": 121.47472,
        "latitude": 31.2286,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Salt Lake City (coming soon)",
        "longitude": -111.5300,
        "latitude": 40.4500,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Helsinki (coming soon)",
        "longitude": 24.5615,
        "latitude": 60.1015,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1
       }
      ]
     },
     "balloon": {
      "horizontalPadding": 15,
      "borderAlpha": 0,
      "borderThickness": 1,
      "verticalPadding": 15
     },
     "areasSettings": {
      "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
      "outlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
      "rollOverOutlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
      "rollOverBrightness": 20,
      "selectedBrightness": 20,
      "selectable": true,
      "unlistedAreasAlpha": 0,
      "unlistedAreasOutlineAlpha": 0
     },
     "imagesSettings": {
      "alpha": 1,
      "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
      "outlineAlpha": 0,
      "rollOverOutlineAlpha": 0,
      "outlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
      "rollOverBrightness": 20,
      "selectedBrightness": 20,
      "selectable": true
     },
     "linesSettings": {
      "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
      "selectable": true,
      "rollOverBrightness": 20,
      "selectedBrightness": 20
     },
     "zoomControl": {
      "zoomControlEnabled": true,
      "homeButtonEnabled": false,
      "panControlEnabled": false,
      "right": 38,
      "bottom": 30,
      "minZoomLevel": 2.25,
      "gridHeight": 100,
      "gridAlpha": 0.1,
      "gridBackgroundAlpha": 0,
      "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "draggerAlpha": 1,
      "buttonCornerRadius": 2
     }
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0;background-color: rgba(80,80,80,1);">
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

amCharts API [here](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts%20amCharts%20API).

Comment: Did you look at the docs? https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/programatically-centering-map-selected-object/

Answer (score 4):

To center the map to the desired part of the map by default, you need to set the combination of `zoomLatitude`, `zoomLongitude`, and `zoomLevel` properties in your dataProvider so that it zooms to the desired section on load. The world maps are Mercator-calibrated so you can use real coordinates to set them. For your case, I chose a `zoomLevel` of 2.5, and set the `zoomLatitude` and `zoomLongitude` over an area in Poland to center it in my demo, but feel free to adjust it further for your usage.

As for disabling the country rollover balloon, you can set `getAreasFromMap` to false (or remove the line in your `dataProvider`), it will disable the rollover for the countries as they won't be automatically defined. You can enable them selectively by adding them into your `dataProvider` if you wish in the `areas` array. You'll have to set the `unlistedAreasAlpha` and `unlistedAreasOutlineAlpha` back to 1 and set the `unlistedAreasColor`, and `unlistedAreasOutlineColor` to the grey you have currently since the countries are no longer listed.

To summarize in code:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("map", {
  // ... 
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    // modify the default zoom
    "zoomLevel": 2.5,
    "zoomLongitude": 18.764648,
    "zoomLatitude": 51.493241,
     // ... 
  },
  // ....
  "areasSettings": {
    // ...
    // add color to unlisted areas since getAreasFromMap was removed from the dataProvider
    "unlistedAreasColor": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
    "unlistedAreasOutlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
});
```

Demo below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>map created with amCharts | amCharts</title>
  <meta name="description" content="map created using amCharts pixel map generator" />

  <!--
   This map was created using Pixel Map Generator by amCharts and is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.
   You may use this map the way you see fit as long as proper attribution to the name of amCharts is given in the form of link to https://pixelmap.amcharts.com/
   To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

   If you would like to use this map without any attribution, you can acquire a commercial license for the JavaScript Maps - a tool that was used to produce this map.
   To do so, visit amCharts Online Store: https://www.amcharts.com/online-store/
  -->

  <!-- amCharts javascript sources -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>

  <!-- amCharts javascript code -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var targetSVG = "M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z";
    AmCharts.makeChart("map", {
      "type": "map",
      "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
      "addClassNames": true,
      "fontSize": 15,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "projection": "mercator",
      "backgroundAlpha": 1,
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
      "dataProvider": {
        "map": "worldLow",
        "zoomLevel": 2.5,
        "zoomLongitude": 18.764648,
        "zoomLatitude": 51.493241,
        "images": [{
          "top": 40,
          "left": 60,
          "width": 80,
          "height": 40,
          "pixelMapperLogo": true,
          "imageURL": "http://pixelmap.amcharts.com/static/img/logo.svg",
          "url": "http://www.amcharts.com"
        }, {
          "selectable": true,
          "title": "Brussels",
          "longitude": 4.2100,
          "latitude": 50.5100,
          "svgPath": targetSVG,
          "color": "#ff1d51",
          "scale": 1,
          "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/brussels/"
        }, {
          "selectable": true,
          "title": "Berlin",
          "longitude": 13.2300,
          "latitude": 52.3100,
          "svgPath": targetSVG,
          "color": "#ff1d51",
          "scale": 1,
          "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/berlin/"
        }, {
          "selectable": true,
          "title": "Graz",
          "longitude": 15.2600,
          "latitude": 47.4000,
          "svgPath": targetSVG,
          "color": "#ff1d51",
          "scale": 1,
          "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/graz/"
        }, {
          "selectable": true,
          "title": "Sofia (coming soon)",
          "longitude": 23.33,
          "latitude": 42.7000,
          "svgPath": targetSVG,
          "color": "#ff1d51",
          "scale": 1
        }, {
          "selectable": true,
          "title": "Shanghai (coming soon)",
          "longitude": 121.47472,
          "latitude": 31.2286,
          "svgPath": targetSVG,
          "color": "#ff1d51",
          "scale": 1
        }, {
          "selectable": true,
          "title": "Salt Lake City (coming soon)",
          "longitude": -111.5300,
          "latitude": 40.4500,
          "svgPath": targetSVG,
          "color": "#ff1d51",
          "scale": 1
        }, {
          "selectable": true,
          "title": "Helsinki (coming soon)",
          "longitude": 24.5615,
          "latitude": 60.1015,
          "svgPath": targetSVG,
          "color": "#ff1d51",
          "scale": 1
        }]
      },
      "balloon": {
        "horizontalPadding": 15,
        "borderAlpha": 0,
        "borderThickness": 1,
        "verticalPadding": 15
      },
      "areasSettings": {
        "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
        "outlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
        "unlistedAreasColor": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
        "unlistedAreasOutlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
        "rollOverOutlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
        "rollOverBrightness": 20,
        "selectedBrightness": 20
      },
      "imagesSettings": {
        "alpha": 1,
        "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
        "outlineAlpha": 0,
        "rollOverOutlineAlpha": 0,
        "outlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
        "rollOverBrightness": 20,
        "selectedBrightness": 20,
        "selectable": true
      },
      "linesSettings": {
        "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
        "selectable": true,
        "rollOverBrightness": 20,
        "selectedBrightness": 20
      },
      "zoomControl": {
        "zoomControlEnabled": true,
        "homeButtonEnabled": false,
        "panControlEnabled": false,
        "right": 38,
        "bottom": 30,
        "minZoomLevel": 2.25,
        "gridHeight": 100,
        "gridAlpha": 0.1,
        "gridBackgroundAlpha": 0,
        "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "draggerAlpha": 1,
        "buttonCornerRadius": 2
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;background-color: rgba(80,80,80,1);">
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>map created with amCharts | amCharts</title>
  <meta name="description" content="map created using amCharts pixel map generator" />

  <!--
   This map was created using Pixel Map Generator by amCharts and is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.
   You may use this map the way you see fit as long as proper attribution to the name of amCharts is given in the form of link to https://pixelmap.amcharts.com/
   To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

   If you would like to use this map without any attribution, you can acquire a commercial license for the JavaScript Maps - a tool that was used to produce this map.
   To do so, visit amCharts Online Store: https://www.amcharts.com/online-store/
  -->

  <!-- amCharts javascript sources -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>

  <!-- amCharts javascript code -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var targetSVG = "M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z";
 map=  AmCharts.makeChart("map",{
     "type": "map",
     "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
     "addClassNames": true,
     "fontSize": 15,
     "color": "#FFFFFF",
     "projection": "mercator",
     "backgroundAlpha": 1,
     "backgroundColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
     "dataProvider": {
                      
      "map": "worldLow",
      "getAreasFromMap": true,
      "images": [
       {
        "top": 40,
        "left": 60,
        "width": 80,
        "height": 40,
        "pixelMapperLogo": true,
        "imageURL": "http://pixelmap.amcharts.com/static/img/logo.svg",
        "url": "http://www.amcharts.com"
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Brussels",
        "longitude": 4.2100,
        "latitude": 50.5100,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1,
        "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/brussels/"
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Berlin",
        "longitude": 13.2300,
        "latitude": 52.3100,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1,
        "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/berlin/"
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Graz",
        "longitude": 15.2600,
        "latitude": 47.4000,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1,
        "url": "https://blockchainhub.net/graz/"
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Sofia (coming soon)",
        "longitude": 23.33,
        "latitude": 42.7000,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Shanghai (coming soon)",
        "longitude": 121.47472,
        "latitude": 31.2286,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Salt Lake City (coming soon)",
        "longitude": -111.5300,
        "latitude": 40.4500,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1
       },
       {
        "selectable": true,
        "title": "Helsinki (coming soon)",
        "longitude": 24.5615,
        "latitude": 60.1015,
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "color": "#ff1d51",
        "scale": 1
       }
      ]
                      
     },
          
     "balloon": {
      "horizontalPadding": 15,
      "borderAlpha": 0,
      "borderThickness": 1,
      "verticalPadding": 15
     },
     "areasSettings": {
      "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
      "outlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
      "rollOverOutlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
      "rollOverBrightness": 20,
      "selectedBrightness": 20,
      "selectable": true,
      "unlistedAreasAlpha": 0,
      "unlistedAreasOutlineAlpha": 0
     },
     "imagesSettings": {
      "alpha": 1,
      "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
      "outlineAlpha": 0,
      "rollOverOutlineAlpha": 0,
      "outlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
      "rollOverBrightness": 20,
      "selectedBrightness": 20,
      "selectable": true
     },
     "linesSettings": {
      "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
      "selectable": true,
      "rollOverBrightness": 20,
      "selectedBrightness": 20
     },
              "showDescriptionOnHover":"false",
     "zoomControl": {
      "zoomControlEnabled": true,
      "homeButtonEnabled": false,
      "panControlEnabled": false,
      "right": 38,
      "bottom": 30,
      "minZoomLevel": 2.25,
      "gridHeight": 100,
      "gridAlpha": 0.1,
      "gridBackgroundAlpha": 0,
      "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "draggerAlpha": 1,
      "buttonCornerRadius": 2
     }
    });
    map.dataProvider.zoomLatitude = "54.5260";
         
      
  </script>
 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0;background-color: rgba(80,80,80,1);">
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```